# Translucent navigation without layout displaying beneath status bar

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using the new Android 4.4 `FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION` flag to turn the navigation bar (back, home button etc) at the bottom of the screen translucent. This works fine but a side effect of this is the layout of my Activity now displays beneath the status bar at the top of the screen (even though I have not set the status bar as being translucent). I want to avoid a hacky fix I.e. applying padding to the top of the layout.

Is there a way to set the navigation as translucent whilst ensuring the status bar appears normally and does NOT allow the layout to display beneath it?

The code I am using is as follows:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    Window w = getWindow();
    w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

ianhanniballake's answer actually works, but you shouldn't use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on the toplevel view. Use this property as following :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <!-- Your other views -->

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you can see, you have to set the color on the top-level view, and put the property on another container.

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your top level view - [android:fitsSystemWindows](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3afitsSystemWindows) will automatically resize the view to take into account the system windows such as the status bar.

Comment: This does not work. It does prevent the view from being positioned under the status bar but it also prevents the view from appearing under the, now translucent, navigation bar - which is effectively useless.